# How To Create This Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
    ![i am showing you an image.
    i want to create this type by using of jquery but i am not getting exactly what i want please help me. ,I have following HTML code which I want to create dynamically by using jQuery AJAX request. My response is in JSON format.
i am showing you an image.
    i want to create this type by using of jquery but i am not getting exactly what i want please help me. ,I have following HTML code which I want to create dynamically by using jQuery AJAX request. My response is in JSON format. 
i am showing you an image.
    i want to create this type by using of jquery but i am not getting exactly what i want please help me. ,I have following HTML code which I want to create dynamically by using jQuery AJAX request. My response is in JSON format.
```

i am showing you an image.
    i want to create this type by using of jquery but i am not getting exactly what i want please help me. ,I have following HTML code which I want to create dynamically by using jQuery AJAX request. My response is in JSON format. 
i am showing you an image.
    i want to create this type by using of jquery but i am not getting exactly what i want please help me. ,I have following HTML code which I want to create dynamically by using jQuery AJAX request. My response is in JSON format. 
i am showing you an image.
    i want to create this type by using of jquery but i am not getting exactly what i want please help me. ,I have following HTML code which I want to create dynamically by using jQuery AJAX request. My response is in JSON format.

```
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
            <legend>Select Locations</legend>
            <input id="checkbox2" name="" type="checkbox"
            />
            <label for="checkbox2">ICU Unit
                <div class="location_detail"> <span class="left">6 Messages</span>
                </div>
            </label>
            <input id="checkbox3" name="" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="checkbox3">CCU Unit
                <div class="location_detail"> <span class="left">6 Messages</span>
                </div>
            </label>
            <input id="checkbox4" name="" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="checkbox4">EU Unit
                <div class="location_detail"> <span class="left">6 Messages</span>
                </div>
            </label>
        </fieldset>

    JSON data looks like this:

        {
            __type="PatientInfo:#DAAB",
            DeptId=14,
            DeptName="GENERAL",
            more...
        }
        1Object{
            __type="PatientInfo:#DAAB",
            DeptId=14,
            DeptName="GENERAL",
            more...
        }
        2Object{
            __type="PatientInfo:#DAAB",
            DeptId=14,
            DeptName="GENERAL",
            more...
        }


    first record looks like this:

        {
            __type:"PatientInfo:#DAAB",
            AcknowledgeComment:null,
            AcknowledgedBy:null,
            DeptId:14,
            DeptName:"GENERAL",
            DeptPhoneNumber:"1234567894",
            ForwardBy:null,
            ForwardComment:null,
            HasECHO:false,
            HasLabReports:false,
            HasLabResults:false,
            HasMR:false,
            HospPhoneNumber:"1234512345",
            IsAlreadyLabSubscribed:false,
            IsEscalatedMessage:false,
            IsEscalationPossible:false,
            IsMessageAcknowledgedBySomeOne:false,
            IsMessageEscalatedBySystem:false,
            IsPrimaryReceiver:true,
            Message:"- ABNORMAL ECG -",
            MessageGenerationDate:"12/20/2012 08:20:24 AM",
            MessageID:768,
            MessageLevel:2,
            MessageStatus:"SENT TO MOBILE",
            MessageStatusID:3,
            MessageType:"EKG",
            PatientFirstName:" 03 ",
            PatientID:"TestPID9480",
            PatientLastName:"Test",
            PatientMiddleInitial:"",
            PatientNamePrefix:"",
            PatientNameSuffix:"",
            RowNumber:1,
            Sender:"Mvisum,",
            SenderId:1,
            Severity:"Level2",
            Subject:"ECG attached for patient - Test, 03 ",
            TotalPatientCount:3,
            UnitId:16,
            UnitName:"Emergency",
            UnitPhoneNumber:"9999999999"
        }


      \[1\]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hgnz2.png][1]
```

Comment: Can you show us how the json response looks like?

Comment: 0
 Object { __type=

"PatientInfo:#DAAB"

, DeptId=

14

, DeptName=

"GENERAL"

, more...}
 
1
 Object { __type=

"PatientInfo:#DAAB"

, DeptId=

14

, DeptName=

"GENERAL"

, more...}
 
2
 Object { __type=

"PatientInfo:#DAAB"

, DeptId=

14

, DeptName=

"GENERAL"

, more...}

Comment: like this my respone from json.

Comment: Please edit it to the original question... comment looks so messy

Comment: you can consider ICU Unit=DeptName and message=DeptId

Comment: Is that really your JSON? It's not even close to valid

Comment: show us the valid json..........

Comment: yes it is my json each paranthesis is as an one record.so there are 3 record currently i am showing you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical" id="fs">
    <legend>Select Locations</legend>

</fieldset>
```

and jquery

```
$.getJSON(url, null, function (data) {
        var $fs = $("#fs");
        $.each(data, function (index, obj) {
            var cbid = "checkbox" + index;
            var $cb = $('<input id="' + cbid + '" name="" type="checkbox" style="float:left;display:inline;"/>');
            var $label = $('<label for="' + cbid + '">').append(obj.DeptName);
            var $div = $('<div class="location_detail">');
            var $span = $("<span class='left'>" + obj.DeptId + "</span>");
            $cb.appendTo($fs);
            $label.appendTo($fs);
            $div.appendTo($label);
            $span.appendTo($div);
        });
    });
```

Update:

Fiddle for changing order of objects:

http://jsfiddle.net/8WbtF/2/

Wrapped the all the checkboxes and labels into one div with display:block to make the arranging easier.

Comment: but how to show checkbox and label on one line,according to the  number of record in json.

Comment: Hi..I want detpId first and then cbid and then checkbox how to rearrage it please tell me.

Comment: By changing order the jq objects are appended to fieldset and modifying the css.

Comment: Hi I have to add the Hr tag after closing of div tag what can i do.my code is as follows

Comment: this is my code :........ var cbid = "checkbox" + i;
            var $itemdiv = $('<div style="display:block;"><hr>');
            var $cb = $('<input id="' + cbid + '" name=""  type="checkbox" />');
            var $label = $('<label for="' + cbid + '" >');
            var $div = $('<div class="location_detail" style="float:left;" >');
            var $span = $("<span class='left'>" + data1[i].DeptName + "</span>");
            $itemdiv.appendTo($fs);
            $label.appendTo($itemdiv);
            $div.appendTo($label);
            $span.appendTo($div);
            $cb.appendTo($itemdiv);

Comment: I really don't think it's that hard to figure out, just do it in the way all the other tags are done.

Comment: jsfiddle you are given me.in that i want to put one hr tag each  record means after every row so can you update your fiddle.means all record being sepearted fro one another.i have to put hr tag at the end of div tag </div> but there are no </div> tag so please help me.thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your object is a array with objects, like this:

```
var data = [
    {
        __type: "PatientInfo:#DAAB",
        DeptId: 14,
        DeptName: "GENERAL"
        //Etc
    }, {
        __type: "PatientInfo:#DAAB",
        DeptId: 14,
        DeptName: "GENERAL"
    } //Etc
];
```

And you have some HTML like this:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical" id="fields">
    <legend>Select Locations</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Then this will work:

```
var fields = document.getElementById('fields');
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    var div =  document.createElement('div');
    var span =  document.createElement('span');

    input.setAttribute('id','checkbox'+(i+1));
    input.setAttribute('type','checkbox');
    label.setAttribute('for','checkbox'+(i+1));
    div.setAttribute('class','location_detail');
    span.setAttribute('class','left');

    fields.appendChild(input);
    fields.appendChild(label);
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i].DeptId));
    label.appendChild(div);
    div.appendChild(span);
    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i].__type));
}
```

**[Working Sample](http://jsbin.com/unodab/2/edit)**